# I can not reach all data in json file as Strapi backend?

Tags: strapi

**https://admin.medicte.ca/Doctors
**https://admin.medicte.ca/Doctors?doctorName_contains=tuysuz

As you can see here, there are two different urls which are strapi json files. The problem here is when I click first link there is only 100 doctor. In CMS. admin panel I can see 143 doctor. If I search by name like in the second url. There is that doctor, which it doesn't appear on the first link. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is called pagination.

If the size of your collection exceeds the page size, simply ask for the next page: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/sort-pagination.html or you can also change the limit in `config/api.js` with

```
// path: ./config/api.js

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  rest: {
    defaultLimit: 100,
    maxLimit: 250,
  },
});
```